# SQL Insert Into Select Statement With Condition

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, sql-insert

I have a table like this :

[image]

I want to insert into detail_salary_table with Insert into Select statement.
I can insert the salary_component item "Salary" with this code

```
INSERT INTO detail_salary_table (date_work, id_emp, salary_component, nominal)
    SELECT  
        date_work, id_emp, 'Salary',
        IIF(DATEDIFF(minute, start_work, finish_work) > 480, 10000, round(convert(float(53), datediff(minute, start_work, finish_work)) / 480, 1) * 10000) 
    FROM 
        attendance_table
```

How to insert the salary_component item "OverTime" with T-SQL like the image?

If I use VB.NET, I can do it with if and loop statement.

Note :

- 480 is fix. 10.000 is fix.
- overtime = finish_work - start_work - 480. It take nominal from overtime_rate_table where the value near to time_in_minutes
- the increment of nominal in overtime_rate_table is not measured. (so, i cannot use * 1000) (example is measured)

The SQL code to create the tables and sample data:

```
create table employee_table 
(
    id_emp int primary key,
    name_emp varchar(200)
);
GO

create table attendance_table 
(
    id_data int primary key identity(1,1),
    date_work date,
    id_emp int,
    start_work datetime,
    finish_work datetime
);
GO

create table overtime_rate_table  
(
    id_data int,
    time_in_minutes int,
    nominal money
);
GO

create table detail_salary_table 
(
    id_data int primary key identity(1,1),
    date_work date,
    id_emp int,
    salary_component varchar(100),
    nominal money
);
GO

insert into employee_table 
values (1, 'Emp A'), (2, 'Emp B'), (3, 'Emp C'), (4, 'Emp D'), (5, 'Emp E');
GO

insert into attendance_table (date_work, id_emp, start_work, finish_work) 
values 
     ('2017-02-01',1,'2017-02-01 08:00','2017-02-01 16:52'),
     ('2017-02-01',2,'2017-02-01 07:45','2017-02-01 16:48'),
     ('2017-02-01',3,'2017-02-01 08:02','2017-02-01 12:05'),
     ('2017-02-01',4,'2017-02-01 07:56','2017-02-01 16:49'),
     ('2017-02-01',5,'2017-02-01 07:30','2017-02-01 18:05'),
     ('2017-02-02',1,'2017-02-02 07:52','2017-02-02 16:23'),
     ('2017-02-02',2,'2017-02-02 07:19','2017-02-02 18:56'),
     ('2017-02-02',3,'2017-02-02 07:55','2017-02-02 18:23'),
     ('2017-02-02',4,'2017-02-02 08:01','2017-02-02 16:01'),
     ('2017-02-02',5,'2017-02-02 07:31','2017-02-02 16:49'),
     ('2017-02-03',1,'2017-02-03 07:52','2017-02-03 17:44'),
     ('2017-02-03',2,'2017-02-03 07:41','2017-02-03 17:23'),
     ('2017-02-03',3,'2017-02-03 07:06','2017-02-03 17:56'),
     ('2017-02-03',4,'2017-02-03 07:56','2017-02-03 19:00'),
     ('2017-02-03',5,'2017-02-03 07:45','2017-02-03 18:56');
GO

insert into overtime_rate_table 
values (1, 15, 1000), (2, 30, 2000), (3, 45, 3000),
       (4, 60, 4000), (5, 75, 5000), (6, 90, 6000),
       (7, 105, 7000), (8, 120, 8000), (9, 135, 9000),
       (10, 150, 10000), (11, 165, 11000), (12, 180, 12000),
       (13, 195, 13000), (14, 210, 14000), (15, 225, 15000);
GO
```

Comment: Your given query **cannot** insert those rows. Those were probably added before.

Comment: [How to create a **Minimal**, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
INSERT INTO detail_salary_table
(date_work,
 id_emp,
 salary_component,
 nominal
)
       SELECT date_work,
              id_emp,
              'OverTime',
              ISNULL(o.Nominal, 0)
       FROM attendance_table a
            LEFT JOIN overtime_rate_table o ON CONVERT( INT, DATEDIFF(minute, a.start_work, a.finish_work) - 480) / 15 * 15 = o.time_in_minutes;
```